# Storing files in multiple directories vs single directory

Tags: file, directory, server, filesystems

I am working on a web server where I have to store many image files of different cities.

 There are two choices :

1. All files can be stored in the same directory or
2. Files of city1 can be stored in city1 directory, files of city2 in city2 directory and so on. Around 20 such directories will be created.

Does it cause any difference in the response time of the server, robustness of the file system, or any other factor? Which is the better choice?

Answer (score 0):

I would argue for **choice 2** because it is better for overview and extenibility. Additionally an existing *filename* in folder `city1` can also be used in folder `city2`. In solution 1 you might have a collision of filenames then. There is no difference in response time worth mentioning. If you do read/write often the same files the server's cache will have a significant role for access time, which is the same either in solution 1 or 2.